# Poisson distribution 3

Tags: statistics

> Two shops $A$ and $B$ have accidents occurring randomly at a rate of two accidents in three months in $A$ and three accidents in four months in $B$. I come to shop $B$ on 11 Jan; I have no effect on the accident rate; what is the probability that I can report 'no accidents so far' on 1 March? Later I am transferred to shop $A$. What is the probability that there will be no accidents in shop $A$ in the next month and one or more accidents in shop $B$?

I have assumed that each month has four weeks and used the Poisson distribution, where $\mu=3/16,T=7,\lambda=21/16,P(B=0)=e^{-21/16}=0.2691$. Am I right so far?

Comment: *I have assumed that each month has four weeks*... What for? This seems unnecessary to use weeks, the homework only mentions months and days.

Comment: I'll assume that one month has 30 days then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $1$ month $= 30$ days. Let $X_i$ be the event of accident in $i$th day in shop $A$ and $Y_i$ be the event of accident in $i$th day in shop $B$. So $X_i \sim P(\frac{2}{90})$ and $Y_i \sim P(\frac{3}{120})$. Here 11 th Jan to 1 Mar We assume total $(21+28+31=80)$ days.

Note that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\sim P(\frac{2n}{90})$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i \sim P(\frac{3n}{120})$

So the probability that you can report 'no accidents so far='$$Pr[\sum_{i=1}^{80}Y_i=0]=\exp{(-\frac{3\cdot 80}{120})}=0.1352$$
Let total days of march is $31$.

Again the probability that there will be no accidents in shop A in the next month and one or more accidents in shop B is =$$\begin{align}P[\sum_{i=1}^{31}X_i=0,\sum_{i=1}^{31}Y_i \geq 1]&= P[\sum_{i=1}^{31}X_i=0]P[\sum_{i=1}^{31}Y_i \geq 1] \\ &=\exp{(-\frac{2\cdot 31}{90})}[1-\exp{(-\frac{3\cdot 31}{120})}]=0.2708\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the well written answer. There was a typo by my teacher so the starting date is 1 Jan.